# "Remote server not found" issue while giving the URL(Intranet Site) to Webbrowser tag in windows phone 7 & 8

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to access a url which is intranet one. It is prompting credentials when I open in built in IE browser and able to open. But when I open same on WebBrowser control, its not asking credentials instead, it is saying **"We can not display this page right now"**.

Then we tried this below code:

```
    public void GetMethodResponse(string _url)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(GetMethodResponseAsync);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(_url));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }


    private void GetMethodResponseAsync(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strResponse = e.Result;
            wbEdit.NavigateToString(strResponse);
            wbEdit.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Here we are getting "Remote server Not Found" Exception.**

And here i also used the **HttpWebRequset class** to pass the credentials but still i am facing the same issue.

I tried Same URL in android Webview control, It is working fine in Android.

Find the Andriod code below:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_crm); 
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();  
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie(); 
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ()); 
            webView.loadUrl("URL");

    }

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
            @Override 
            public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, 
                    HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) { 
                handler.proceed("domain\\username", "password"); 
            } 
    }
```

I am able to open my URL in Webview control of android application.

**Please help here so that i can access my URL in windows phone Webbrowser control**.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you don't include the credentials? What if you try and go to the URI in IE on the device? Is the device definitely able to access the same domain?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I tried same URL in IE of my Device. While i am accessing the URL, IE prompted for me to enter the Details for Domain, Username and Password after entering the credentials i am able to access the URL in IE. But while i am accessing the URL in Webbrowser tag i did not get prompt box to enter the credentials. If i simply give the URL to Webbrowser tag using source attribute (i have not given the credentials) it is saying that "Unauthriozed Access" but if i use WebClient as above (i have not given the credentials) even though it is saying that "Remote server not found"

Comment: It sounds like the OS is returning the wrong error message. In that you have it working on one platform but not on another you should look at the actual information that is sent of the network, not just at what data you think you're passing. Use Fiddler, or WireShark, or similar to compare what the two platforms are actually sending.